# why array variable may not be initialized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have this very simply code:

```
uint16_t dataSize = 5;
uint8_t wdata[dataSize] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

and I get error message:

```
variable "wdata" may not be initialized
uint8_t wdata[dataSize]
```

It is in a file with .ccp extension.  I have other test case files with similar statement and error message.

The code compiles with `gcc` without any problem.  However, Visual Studio Code C++ IntelliSense is the one that reports the error.

Comment: `uint8_t wdata[dataSize]` This is not valid C++ code. In some compilers it is possible but don't do this. Variable length arrays is generally not supported.

Comment: In C (from C99) you can declare [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array), but not in C++. Some compilers allow you to do that as an extension.

Comment: make `dataSize` a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merek R's advice turned out to be the solution:

```
const uint16_t dataSize = 5;
uint8_t wdata[dataSize] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Answer (score 1):

DimChtz is correct, you can't initialise an array with size at compile time with a variable.

You would be better off just initialising the array with no size:

```
uint16_t dataSize = 5;
uint8_t wdata[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Comment: Better yet, you could calculate `dataSize` based on the size of `wdata`.